# Is there a way to send the pixel information of a very big sized picture to multiple excel files using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to send the pixel information of a picture to an excel file. But I was constantly getting the size errors. So I tried to make several excel files to copy the information. But now I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d01004947e92> in <module>()
     14 #df.toexcel(filepath,index=False)
     15 
---> 16 df1 = df(img[0:1000000])
     17 df2 = df(img[1000000:2000000])
     18 df3 = df(img[2000000:3000000])

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Can you help me to understand what causes this. Unfortunately I am very new with the python language.

````
#Getting Pixel Values
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame(img.flatten())


df1 = df(img[0:1000000])
df2 = df(img[1000000:2000000])
df3 = df(img[2000000:3000000])
df4 = df(img[3000000:4000000])
df5 = df(img[4000000:5000000])
df6 = df(img[5000000:6000000])
df7 = df(img[6000000:7000000])
df8 = df(img[7000000:8000000])
df9 = df(img[8000000:9000000])
df10= df(img[9000000:10000000])

filepath1='pixel_values1.xlsx'
filepath2='pixel_values2.xlsx'
filepath3='pixel_values3.xlsx'
filepath4='pixel_values4.xlsx'
filepath5='pixel_values5.xlsx'
filepath6='pixel_values6.xlsx'
filepath7='pixel_values7.xlsx'
filepath8='pixel_values8.xlsx'
filepath9='pixel_values9.xlsx'
filepath10='pixel_values10.xlsx'

df1.to_excel(filepath1,index=False)
df2.to_excel(filepath2,index=False)
df3.to_excel(filepath3,index=False)
df4.to_excel(filepath4,index=False)
df5.to_excel(filepath5,index=False)
df6.to_excel(filepath6,index=False)
df7.to_excel(filepath7,index=False)
df8.to_excel(filepath8,index=False)
df9.to_excel(filepath9,index=False)
df10.to_excel(filepath10,index=False)```
````

Comment: What are you trying to set `df1` equal to? Is it all columns of the DataFrame, from rows 0 to 1000000? Or is it row 0, columns 0 to 1000000?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to store pixel values in Excel? It would be extremely slow, inefficient and cumbersome. There's a reason folks use image storage formats such as PNG, JPEG and TIFF and image processing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you've read your image into a numpy array: `img`.

After that, you converted `img` to a DataFrame, `df` in the line:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(img.flatten())
```

The error is raised because you're trying to call `df` with a slice of the original array.

Instead, you want to take slices of `df` by it's own index, like so:

```
df1 = df[0:1000000]
```

Keep in mind that this way you lose information because of the flattening of the original, multidimensional array!

Comment: Thank you very much sir I solved the problem by clipping the image and eliminating the undesired pixel values.